# Pthreads and shared memory in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, shared-memory

Can anyone tell me why my shared memory data structure (implemented using sys/shm.h) is not being read correctly by pthreads? This is an edited version of my question, with a reduced amount of code.  Hopefully its easier to navigate.

Initially, the structure being referenced is created in shared memory space, so two different applications can read and write to it.  The aim: to have one application update the shared structure, and the other read it using pthreads.  So far everything things are working to an extent.  Both applications can read and write to the shared memory, except the pthreads. they don't seem to pick up the modified shared structure?

An overview of the code is below. It is based on a basic runtime system, however, it is not overly complicated.  The function executed within the pthreads is:

```
void* do_work(void *p)
```

The shared structure is:

```
typedef struct WL_CTRL_T
```

Currently all i am trying do is print out the elements of the array.  Initially all elements are set to true.  Halfway through the execution, using GDB to halt the process, i update the structure from outside, using the other application, by changing elements 0 and 1 to false, then continue to the process.  At this i also print out the state of the array from each application via the sequential code, and the print out is correct.  However, when the threads are set off, they print the original state of the array, all true...

The structure contains an array of structs, where the active bool field is read by the pthread

I have tried many ways to try and correct this problem, but no joy.

Any advice appreciated, thanks :-)

```
/*controller api.h*/

typedef struct WL_CTRL_T
{
  int targetNumThreads;
  int sizeBuf;
  int numEntries;
  int nextIdx;
  thread_state_control_t volatile thread_state_control[THREAD_NUM];
  mon_entry_t buffer[];
} wl_ctrl_t;

typedef struct THREADPOOL_T
{
  int num_threads;
  int qsize;
  pthread_t *threads;
  todo_t *qhead;
  todo_t *qtail;
  pthread_mutex_t qlock;
  pthread_cond_t q_not_empty;
  pthread_cond_t q_empty;
  int shutdown;
  int dont_accept;
}threadpool_t;

typedef struct TODO_T
{
  void (*routine) (void*);
  void * arg;
  int lock;
  struct todo_t* next;
} todo_t;
```

The function assigned to the pthread

```
/********************************************************************
*
* do_work:
*
*      this is the reusable thread, assigned work via the dispatch
*      function.
*
********************************************************************/

void* do_work(void *p) 
{  
  int c = 0;
  thread_args_t *thread_args = (thread_args_t*)p; 
  threadpool_t *pool = thread_args->threadpool;
  todo_t* workload;
  wl_ctrl_t volatile *wcc = thread_args->wl_ctrl;

  while(1) 
  {
    pool->qsize = pool->qsize;

    /* while work que is empty, spinlock */
    while( pool->qsize == 0)  
    {   
      if(c<1)
       printf("thread: %d spin-lock \n", thread_args->thread_id);
      c++; 
  }   

  /* update the threadpool, minus current workload */
  workload = pool->qhead;    
  pool->qsize--;    
  if(pool->qsize == 0)  
  {   
    pool->qhead = NULL;
    pool->qtail = NULL;
  }   
  else 
  {   
    pool->qhead = workload->next;
  }   

  /* execute workload */
  (workload->routine) (workload->arg);  
  free(workload);

  /* check this threads wait state */
  printf("In thread: %d\n",wcc->thread_state_control[thread_args->thread_id].active);                    
  }
}
```

Comment: When you use shared memory, you should always declare the struct pointers as "volatile". This tells the compiler that the data inside those structs (that reside inside shared memory) can change on their own and the compiler cannot cache reads. Don't know if that's the source of the problem, though.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I have added volatile to vars and structs, and i have also stopped all gcc optimisations via -O0, but still the problem persists.

Comment: Usually separate threads/processes reading/writing a common object use some type of "traffic cop" like a semaphore.  I do not see how one  is used. You have a mutex.  A mutex should be accessible by all readers/writers.  It does not appear to be globally accessible.